# MySql with Mac os

Tags: ios4

I want to use MySql database as centralised database for storing user informations(credentials) for an iPhone application.MySql is not installed in my system.Can anyone tell me how to use MySql in mac os.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL manual has a section on installing [MySQL on OS X](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/macosx-installation.html)

Obviously, to access it from an iPhone application you will then have to configure it to be exposed over the network (not a good idea except possibly for LAN use only) or put something in between the database and the world (a Web Service is the usual approach).

If you mean that you want to install it on iOS, then forget it. There isn't an iOS version. Look to SQLite instead. AFAIK it is the usual approach for SQL on that platform.